# Do I need to provide cast methods for cast operator overloads in C#, to allow people to use in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, casting, operator-overloading

I read somewhere that older VB .net (pre VB .NET 2005?) couldn't use overloaded operators in a C# class. Is it true for overloaded cast operators?

Either way do you guys think it's a disadvantage for a C# class library not to include them and arithmetic methods as actual methods for other languages, like:

```
ToDouble
ToFloat
FromDouble
Add
Subtract
Multiply
Divide
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB people are used to doing CType (much more than DirectCast) so instead of providing extra methods make sure you support CType (look in Reflector to see which classes it actually uses)